# Aeson lazy parser

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

The Aeson library offers two flavors of json parser: a strict one and a lazy one. The lazy one claims to save time but creat thunks, whereas the strict one saves space and takes more time (both if the data isn't accessed frequently). I have the following toy program to see the difference between them, but the profiles are identical:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString as P
import System.Environment

main = do
    [fn] <- getArgs
    fc <- B.readFile fn
    let r = P.parse json' fc
    case r
      of Done _ _ -> print ":)"
         _   -> print ":("
```

Two parsers also have identical performance when the program access the data fully:

```
    ...
    case r
      of Done _ j -> print j
         _   -> print ":("
```

Why doesn't the lazy version save time in the first program and waste space in the second? Is there an example where one of the parsers clearly wins?

Update: Following is my recent experiment with `FromJSON`, which also failed to differentiate `decode` from `decode'`

```
Data Weirder = Weirder

instance FromJSON Weirder where
    parseJSON (Number n) = return $! undefined -- $! trace "weirdercalled" Weirder -- `seq` Weirder

main = do
    [fn] <- getArgs
    fc <- B.readFile fn
    let Just rs = decode fc :: Maybe [Weirder]
    print $ length rs
```

I've tried printing `head`, `last`, flipping bangs and inserting `seq`, yet all the same...

Comment: first the obvious question: where your files big enough to make the parsing *observable* ?

Comment: @Carsten I tried json file of size ~20M, is that big enough?

Comment: `json'` does no interesting computation (just applies constructors), so there is no(t enough) computation for laziness to delay. Do something more interesting, like parsing a number and returning `last [n..maxBound]` as the value of the parse, and you will see the difference. (Didn't turn this into an answer because every time I touch aeson I get lost in a maze of twisty little `Parser` types and `parse` functions, all alike.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Are you sure? The `Value` construction in aeson is strict. The aeson parsing function reports error; in order to do that, it has to go  check, that the element is correct and build the aeson `Value`, then go  through the `parseJSON` and custom parsing. It seems to me there is no residual laziness there.

Comment: @ondra I think we are in agreement! You say "there is no residual laziness", I say "there is not enough computation for laziness to delay". What are you asking if I'm sure about?

Comment: @DanielWagner I might got confused here; it's that it seems to me that `json'` and `json` are completely identical as all the `Value` parameters are strict anyway and the difference in the source code doesn't matter. Is that what you are saying or am I wrong?

Comment: @ondra I was wondering the same, and none of my experiments show difference between them. I opened an issue and will report what they reply.

Comment: @ondra Aha, it seems I may have misunderstood the question somewhat. Is the question here specifically about `json` vs `json'`, or is it about lazy parsers vs strict parsers in general?

Comment: @DanielWagner It seems to me that `json` and `json'` are the only place the library has an option of being lazy or strict.

Comment: @rem Not so -- the whole `FromJSON` business of converting a JSON `Value` into your semantic value offers a whole host of opportunities for inserting strictness bugs. ;-)

Comment: @DanielWagner Do you have an example? A [discussion](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/37) on their repo doesn't mention anything about `FromJSON`, yet it looks like that's when they introduced the 2 different parsers. I also updated the question with a recent experiment.

Comment: @rem Yes, sure: `foo x = loop <$ fromJSON x`

Comment: @DanielWagner Which `loop` do you mean? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @rem Pick any non-terminating (or even merely long-running) loop you like. `loop = go 0 where go x = go (x+1)` would do.